# Scraping a random word from randomlists.com BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My project involves me scraping random words from https://www.randomlists.com/random-vocabulary-words and creating a multiple choice question using the words scraped off the website.

The data I need to scrape is in a `<div>` with class="Rand-stage", specifically the `<ol>` tag under it. I need to obtain the words in `<li>` tags under `<ol>` after doing this. I've attached an image of this. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLlWZ.png)

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
url = https://www.randomlists.com/random-vocabulary-words 
r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

result = []
for li in soup.find('ol', class_='rand_large').find_all('li'):
    result.append(list(li.stripped_strings))

print(result)
```

Now, I don't know how to scrape the content in the `<ol>` tags, or if that is the content that I need to scrape in the first place, in order to get the randomized words(and their meanings, also in `<li>` tags).

Actually, when the code ran, it didn't display any output. Instead, it threw an

> error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all')

Comment: It looks like `rand_large` is a class in the <li> tag, not the <ol> tag, so the first `soup.find` shouldn't find anything. Are you picking up too much junk when just doing a `soup.find_all('li')`?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Actually, when the code ran, it didn't display any output. Instead, it threw an error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

Content is served dynamically by website, so you wont find the elements your searching for in your `soup`.

So following error appears, cause `soup.find('ol', class_='rand_large')` do not find the element in the response and thats why also your `find_all()` fails:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

#### How to fix?

- use solutions that will render the html like selenium
- use an api that will provide the information (https://www.randomlists.com/data/vocabulary-words.json)

The following line will give you a random set of 3 dicts with word and detail:

```
random.choices(r.json()['data'], k=3)
```

#### Example

```
import requests, random

url =  'https://www.randomlists.com/data/vocabulary-words.json'
r = requests.get(url)

random.choices(r.json()['data'], k=3)
```

#### Output

```
[{'name': 'attenuate', 'detail': 'make thin. weaken enervate'},
 {'name': 'savant', 'detail': 'person of great learning'},
 {'name': 'fledged', 'detail': 'able to fly trained experienced'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this immediately and update

Comment: I just ran the code, and it threw another error, NameError: name 'headers' is not defined. What is 'headers' here, and how do I define it? I haven't worked with .json before so I'm a little confused.

Comment: My fault - Edited the example, you do not have to provide headers, it cames from my standard setup - apologies for this.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! You've been of great help, I can move ahead with my project now :)